# Is a berit milah performed by a female jewish mohel halachically valid?

Tags: halacha

Is a jewish female pediatrician permitted to perform
The mitzvah of berit milah on a jewish infant?
If such a berit milah is performed by the female
Mohel. When the infant grows to maturity
Is he required to get himself circumcised again
By a jewish male mohel??
Thank you.

Comment: FYI - My 2nd cousin who is a local *mohel* told me that a *mohel* is medically considered a "male gynecologist". Not meaning that he's a gynecologist who happens to be a male, but a gynecologist  who medically treats other males.

Comment: The mila of the son of Moshe Rabenu is kosher?

Comment: We have no way of knowing if moshe rebenu's son needed a second symbolic berit milah where a drop of blood is drawn.